# Trouble with Different Python Environments, Anaconda and FEniCS

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm working on MacOs, and I am trying to run finite elements on Python using the FEniCS library.

I use Jupyter notebooks, and in the past, I've had to source my anaconda installation as follows, to run things well:

```
source activate ~/../my_user_name/anaconda3
```

I am not sure, but I think this activates a separate environment for Python installations managed by Anaconda.

To install FEniCS, I ran the following commands:

```
conda create -n fenicsproject -c conda-forge fenics
source activate fenicsproject
```

Now when I try to run a Python script or a Jupyter notebook, I no longer have access to the standard libraries such as **matplotlib**.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue, and could you help me manage these multiple environments/installations of Python?

Comment: Python virtual environments are separate from your main Python installation(s). So when you create a new environment e.g. `fenicsproject`, you need to reinstall third-party modules like Matplotlib into that environment while it's activated.

Comment: When I try installing matplotlib using pip3 in the `fenicsproject` environment , I get `Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.1.0)`.

Comment: You need to activate the environment before you install anything. So try `source activate fenicsproject` before running the pip install command (more modern installations use `conda` instead of `source`)